# Dragging and Dropping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a [sticky note system](http://code.google.com/p/sticky-note-system/downloads/detail?name=draggingpractice.htm&can=2&q=&surl=1&safe=active#makechanges), and I want the sticky notes to be draggable with javascript. I found a drag and drop script on this [site](http://luke.breuer.com/) which was quite useful to me. But I have a “drag bar” that is inside the sticky note div which is supposed to be the only place where you can drag that specific sticky note. The script I have drags only what the cursor is clicking on and I want it to drag the “.dragbar” div’s parent element, “.parent”.

Right now, the script is set to drag .parent when you click on .parent. How, in this code can I select the parent div of “.dragbar”, which is “.parent”?

If I make the script select .dragbar, it just moves the dragbar around inside the .parent. note: the script is the original code, except the selector names in lines 87 and 95 are changed from “drag” to “parent”.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .pagecontent {
                width:98%;
                height:96%;
                overflow:hidden;
                background:lightyellow;
                border:1px solid black;
                padding:10px;
            }
            .parent {
                position:relative;
                height:300px;
                width:300px;
                background-color:gray;
                border:1px solid black;
                float:left;
                margin:0 10px 0 0;
                overflow:auto;
            }
            .dragbar {
                height:50px;
                width:300px;
                background:lightgray;
                cursor:move;
                position:relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="pagecontent">
            <h1>Dragging Practice</h1>
            <h3>Drag and drop the parent div by using the child dragbar</h3>
            <pre id="debug">mouse up</pre>
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="dragbar">I am the Child, my class is .dragbar</div>I am the Parent, my class is
                .parent</div>
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="dragbar">I am the Child, my class is .dragbar</div>I am the Parent, my class is
                .parent</div>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                <!--
                // this is simply a shortcut for the eyes and fingers
                function $(id) {
                    return document.getElementById(id);
                }
                var _startX = 0; // mouse starting positions
                var _startY = 0;
                var _offsetX = 0; // current element offset
                var _offsetY = 0;
                var _dragElement; // needs to be passed from OnMouseDown to OnMouseMove
                var _oldZIndex = 0; // we temporarily increase the z-index during drag
                var _debug = $('debug'); // makes life easier
                InitDragDrop();

                function InitDragDrop() {
                    document.onmousedown = OnMouseDown;
                    document.onmouseup = OnMouseUp;
                }

                function OnMouseDown(e) {
                    // IE is retarded and doesn't pass the event object
                    if (e == null) e = window.event;
                    // IE uses srcElement, others use target
                    var target = e.target != null ? e.target : e.srcElement;
                    _debug.innerHTML = target.className == 'parent' //Selector
                    ?
                    'draggable element clicked' : 'NON-draggable element clicked';
                    // for IE, left click == 1
                    // for Firefox, left click == 0
                    if ((e.button == 1 && window.event != null || e.button == 0) && target.className == 'parent') //Selector
                    {
                        // grab the mouse position
                        _startX = e.clientX;
                        _startY = e.clientY;
                        // grab the clicked element's position
                        _offsetX = ExtractNumber(target.style.left);
                        _offsetY = ExtractNumber(target.style.top);
                        // bring the clicked element to the front while it is being dragged
                        _oldZIndex = target.style.zIndex;
                        target.style.zIndex = 10000;
                        // we need to access the element in OnMouseMove
                        _dragElement = target;
                        // tell our code to start moving the element with the mouse
                        document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove;
                        // cancel out any text selections
                        document.body.focus();
                        // prevent text selection in IE
                        document.onselectstart = function () {
                            return false;
                        };
                        // prevent IE from trying to drag an image
                        target.ondragstart = function () {
                            return false;
                        };
                        // prevent text selection (except IE)
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                function ExtractNumber(value) {
                    var n = parseInt(value);
                    return n == null || isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
                }

                function OnMouseMove(e) {
                    if (e == null) var e = window.event;
                    // this is the actual "drag code"
                    _dragElement.style.left = (_offsetX + e.clientX - _startX) + 'px';
                    _dragElement.style.top = (_offsetY + e.clientY - _startY) + 'px';
                    _debug.innerHTML = '(' + _dragElement.style.left + ', ' + _dragElement.style.top + ')';
                }

                function OnMouseUp(e) {
                    if (_dragElement != null) {
                        _dragElement.style.zIndex = _oldZIndex;
                        // we're done with these events until the next OnMouseDown
                        document.onmousemove = null;
                        document.onselectstart = null;
                        _dragElement.ondragstart = null;
                        // this is how we know we're not dragging
                        _dragElement = null;
                        _debug.innerHTML = 'mouse up';
                    }
                }
                //-->
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use code that includes comments such as "IE is retarded". Such a comment indicates a coder who has obviously lived with the "luxury" of a "superior browser" for far too long and will never appreciate the progress IE9 and IE10 are making. Considering the coder then proceeds to use `innerHTML` - a property Microsoft invented (!) - he/she comes off as a complete hypocrite. That said, I don't use other people's code anyway, I write it myself XD

Comment: I myself am totally unopposed to IE, and am quite fond of it with it's recent progress in IE8 and IE9. I guess I just forgot to take that comment out, but I don't condone use of that language in any form of conversation. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I wasn't really criticising you, more the person who wrote that code in the first place.

Comment: Thanks to Colin for making my code look nice

Comment: its okay. i take no offense to that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you look into [jQuery UI's draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/). These will undoubtedly be more powerful than the script you linked, and you can set up elements to be draggable with jQuery's powerful selectors, and droppable only within certain elements.